# CRM/Core/Config.php line 41 throwing 500 error with new require_once api/api.php

Tags: api, configuration, upgrade, 500

Just updated our WP install from 4.7.22 to 4.7.23 -- but can't run the db update script, because whenever I rename the 4.7.23 folder to *civicrm*, I subsequently get 500 internal server errors while trying to load *any* civicrm pages. Error log indicates a problem at line 41 in CRM/Core/Config.php, which is `require_once 'api/api.php';` ... so I searched the previous working iteration (it runs fine when I switch back to 4.7.22) and there is no mention of `api/api.php` anywhere. So I assume this line is new in 4.7.23, and I have to wonder why it's making civicrm completely unusable for our site.

Ideas?

More detail from the error message:

`PHP Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'api/api.php' (include_path='.:/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm:/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages:/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom:/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_socket:/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/net_smtp:/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/validate_finance_creditcard:.:/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/:/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm//packages:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php on line 41`

Answer (score 1):

First, let the record show that I am an idiot.

After uploading 4.7.23 (the new version) to /wp-content/plugins, I neglected to copy the pre-existing *civicrm.config.php* into /wp-content/plugins/civicrm4.7.23/civicrm ... thereby depriving the system of (at very least) a working value for `$civicrm_root`.

It was suggested to me that my civicrm.config.php was probably off, and I checked it just to make sure the `$civicrm_root` value made sense. The value was good, but the file I was checking was located outside of the plugins directory -- this was a clue, and I missed it. As I said, I'm an idiot.

Of course, once I copied the old civicrm.config.php into the new /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm, everything worked perfectly. Except for CRON jobs, of course -- but that's another matter.

Answer (score 0):

Ok that's odd - `require_once 'api/api/php';`
has been there since CiviCRM switched from SVN to GitHub.

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blame/master/CRM/Core/Config.php#L41

[image]

So something else is going on; do you perhaps have two civicrm directories in your file structure? Simply renaming 4.7.22 to civicrm-old and 4.7.23 to civicrm will not work. Make sure to move the civicrm-old completely out and away.

Added: make sure you do everything in exact order:

- move 4.7.23 code out and away
- revert back to 4.7.22 db
- move 4.7.22 code -> civicrm
- make sure it's working
- remove 4.7.22 code out and way
- put the 4.7.23 code -> civicrm
- run the database upgrade script
- make sure it's working

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Karin. You're absolutely right: `require_once 'api/api/php';` is right where it should be in 4.7.22 -- I was in a rush to post my question, and I made the stupid mistake of trusting the search engine in my file manager when it found the string in 4.7.23 and didn't find it in the previous version. I had to open Config.php in 4.7.22 just now to see that it was there.
In past updates, I've never had a problem playing the name game with the civicrm directories. Upload the new, rename the new and the old, and run the db update script ... but not this time.

Comment: That said, moving the old civicrm directory out of my root directory doesn't help. When I do that, I still get a 500 error with every civi page I try to access. Something is amiss in 4.7.23, but I have no idea *what*.

Comment: There are no widespread install issues for 4.7.23 so this is specific to your setup/procedures. Added some notes to my answer.

Comment: Finally realized my omission of pasting the old civicrm.config.php into the new civicrm/civicrm folder was breaking the system. There was no need to move 4.7.22 away -- once I renamed the civicrm folder, it became effectively inactive, and the newly renamed civicrm folder (previously 4.7.23) became active. Now that the current version is installed & working and the db was successfully upgraded, I can remove the 4.7.22 folder.